# Webservice App - Security for Application (Login, Userdata etc.)

Tags: php, mysql, web-services, security

I'm creating an application for Android and iOS where user have to set up an account with a username, password and a mail address for sending there password in case they forgot it. It's a kind of a game, so it will also save their wins and losses in a MySQL-database. So not really personal data (like address or phone number).

The app talks to the MySQL database via PHP-Scripts(JSON and POST http-method).
So in fact that I don't have a lot of security knowledge, I would like to know how to transmit the data secure from the application to the server. Is it save to send the data to the PHP-Script via POST? I use the md5-hash for saving the password in the database.

And how to make sure, that the data was send from a mobile phone with an active account?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

"I use the md5-hash for saving the password in the database."

This is bad. Use `password_hash()` and `password_verify()` instead of MD5.

"I would like to know how to transmit the data secure from the application to the server."

Serve over HTTPS instead of HTTP. Pin certificates if you're especially paranoid.

"[H]ow to make sure, that the data was send from a mobile phone with an active account?"

There is no way to make absolute sure. Clients can and will lie. Attackers can spoof user agents and defeat any fingerprinting method you can devise.

Comment: Can you tell me how to send it over HTTPS? I will try `password_hash()` and `password_verify()`, thanks!

Comment: You need to set up your webserver to use HTTPS. You can get your own free SSL/TLS certificate from StartSSL.com or just use CloudFlare for your DNS/CDN/reverse proxy